# What parameter to send with setexpresscheckout to have creating a paypal account voluntarilly

Tags: paypal

As the title states, what parameters do i have to send with the setexpresscheckout api call to have creating an acount optional?

Comment: I have a buisness seller account. So that is not the problem. And i have tried with solutiontype=Sole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you send the NVP `SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole`, buyers will see "Don't have a PayPal Account" link on the page that will allow them to pay with a credit card or , providing that merchant account is based in the US, UK, or Canada, and the primary email address is confirmed.

Comment: I have sent that parameter, also i sent an argument to get the landingpage to be billing and that works.
I have another website and there it works without pp account so it should not be a problemt with my merchant account, so is it anything else other than SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole i have to set?

Comment: If LANDINGPAGE=Billing is working for you I would use that. SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole has always been the "go to" solution for this issue, unless there is an underlying account problem, such as the email address not being confirmed.

Comment: Got it working. The problen was a cookie in my browser. You have to login if youve logged in before.